# Stored procedure not working in WHM panel

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to access data from MySQL in live server through a stored procedure, but I am not able to access it. The same code is working perfectly in local server.

```
public static String addNews(String wl_id,String news){
    String news_msg = "";
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement stmt = null;

    try{
        con = ConnectionFactory.getNewConnection();
        stmt=con.prepareCall("{call Updatenews(?,?,?)}");
        stmt.setString(1, news);
        stmt.setString(2, wl_id);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        news_msg=stmt.getString(3);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try{
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return news_msg;
}
```

---

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Updatenews`(IN news
varchar(200),IN wl_id2 varchar(15),  OUT out_result Varchar(20))          
BEGIN
select news into out_result from reseller_news where wl_id=wl_id2;
if (out_result is not null)
then

update reseller_news set news=news where wl_id=wl_id2;

Set out_result='News Updated';
else

insert into reseller_news(wl_id,news) values(wl_id2,news);
Set out_result='News Inserted';
commit;

END if;
END
```

Comment: Please provide more info regarding WHM panel, as they provide tools already to access db

Comment: what information you need of WHM panel ?? this same codes works find in my local computer same thing when i upload in server its not accessing the database but i can run from phpmyadmin but from my java code its not accessing please give me solution regarding this. Does store procedure needs some permission from any settings??

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam please give me solution regarding this problem been stuck in this problem from 2 days need an urgent soltuion

Comment: Is there phpmyadmin under WHM control panel?

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam actually its a vps server which provide cpanel for every domain which has phpmyadmin , mate store procedure is executing directly from phpmyadmin and affecting the database but when trying from java code its not acccessing database please let me know the solution it will be very much helpful indeed